# How do I find the ID of the row that my other rows are duplicated of in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

so I'm looking for an efficient way to do the following:

Let's say I have col A and B where B contains duplicated values. I need to set col C so that it contains the value in col A of the row that it's the duplicate of

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   Col A   |   Col B   |   Col C   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     1     |   apple   |           |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     2     |   apple   |     1     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     3     |   pear    |           |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     4     |   pear    |     3     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     5     |   pear    |     3     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     6     |   lime    |           |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     7     |  orange   |           |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     8     |  orange   |     7     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

I have tried using drop_duplicates to create a temporary df of the unique value in col B only and merge it back to the original df. Then I set col C with the value from col A. However, it think this method is too convoluted and run quite slow.

EDIT: I added a few more row to expand the example data. In the case of lime, there is no duplicated row found so Col C should be empty. For pear, there are 3 duplicates values found so the first one should be empty and the other 2 should reference this first row in Col C.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this :

Get an identifier for the duplicate rows based on `Col B` :

```
df["temp"] = df.duplicated("Col B")
```

Create a column to pull values from `Col A` where the temporary column is `True`

```
df["Col C"] = np.where(df.temp == 1, np.nan, df["Col A"])
```

Next steps is to downward fill

```
df["Col C"] = df["Col C"].ffill()
```

Replace entries in `Col C` with null for entries where `temp` is `False`

```
df["Col C"] = np.where(df.temp == 0, np.nan, df["Col C"])
```

Job is complete, you can get rid of the temporary column

```
df = df.drop("temp", axis=1)
df

    Col A   Col B   Col C
0   1   apple   NaN
1   2   apple   1.0
2   3   pear    NaN
3   4   pear    3.0
4   5   pear    3.0
5   6   lime    NaN
6   7   orange  NaN
7   8   orange  7.0
```

Comment: hi, thank you. I tried this. It works when there are only 1 duplicate. However, when there are more than 1, it doesn't return the right answer

Comment: thought as much. Kindly share some more data then with more duplicate rows

Comment: hey, thank you. It works but the data frame has to be sorted first so all the duplicated rows are next to each other

Comment: yes. I think that's a caveat of my solution that I should have mentioned. I just assumed. Thanks.